# Как сделать, чтобы при создании записи создавался блок с этой записью

Tags: python, django

При разработке сайта назрел такой вопрос: как я могу сделать так, чтобы при добавлении записи генерировался блок с этой записью. Сначала я подумал, что нужно создать очередь из записей; потом разобрался с шаблонизатором, чтобы можно было создавать определённый блок с записью. По моей логике, так как есть очередь из записей, самые новые записи будут применятся к новосозданным блокам. Но тут нужен ваш совет: просто не знаю, работает ли это так, как я задумывал или нет. Для справки скажу, что сайт который я сейчас делаю - это просто практика для большего понимания django.
Даже не знаю, есть ли смысл скидывать вам код чего-либо.

Но всё-таки вот код от models.py:

```
class Goods(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

а вот и код от очереди, то есть views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'article/sale.html'
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'
    def get_queryset(self):
    return Goods.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
```

вот код блока:

```
       <td class ="sale">
     {% for good in goods %}
    <img class="image" src="{{good.image_sale.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
      {% for good in goods %}
        <h1 class="description">{{ good.description_text }}</h1>
      {% endfor %}
  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
    <span >Купить</span></a>
  {% for good in goods %}
        <h1 class="price" >{{ good.price_text }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
  </td>
```

Comment: Учтоните, пожалуйста, что такое блок с записью

Comment: @nomnoms12 блок это скорее моё понятие, но вот я в вопросе добавил

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что Вы хотите для каждой записи вывести фото, описание и цену? Если да, то Вам не нужно 3 цикла, достаточно одного, в теле которого Вы всё и выведете

Comment: @nomnoms12 да вы правильно понимайте, с циклами это не проблема, как мне реализовать то что в вопросе ?

Comment: может для начала [:1] убрать?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Я поменял код, вот что я переписал

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается вся проблема была в строчке:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    return Goods.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
```

Всёго-то нужно было заменить её на этот код:

```
    def products(request):
    queryset = Goods.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'queryset': queryset})
```

Итоговый код:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'article/sale.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def products(request):
    queryset = Goods.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'queryset': queryset})
```

код страницы:

```
       <td class ="sale">
 {% for good in goods %}
<img class="image" src="{{ good.image.url }}">


    <h1 class="description">{{ good.description }}</h1>

  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
   <span >Купить</span></a>

    <h1 class="price" >{{ good.price }} uah</h1>
  {% endfor %}
  </td>
```

однако вопрос про добавление блоков остаётся актуальным